# How can i force a socket timeout in privoxy even on on-going connection?

Tags: sockets, privoxy

I would like to drop the on-going connection after a certain time.

I checked the privoxy configuration options [here](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html) and found 'socket-timeout'.

> 7.6.8. socket-timeout
>
> Specifies:
>
> Number of seconds after which a socket times out if no data is received.

Is there a specific configuration ( or paction file rule ) which allows a socket to timeout even in case of ongoing traffic/connection for the socket?

Specifically, the connection should "drop" or result in an error on reaching this timeout.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Comment: Cool.. I added a post here.. https://superuser.com/questions/1315485 thanks! @JamesKPolk